# AVFoundation - How save AVCaptureMovieFileDataOutput to file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapturemoviefileoutput

I've been going through the [AV Foundation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html). In particular I've been trying to get the "Putting it all together" part in the "Media Capture" section to work. I've made some minor changes to the code in the tutorial, but nothing that should have much impact. What I'm confused about it how to actually save a movie file from the AVCaptureMovieFileDataOutput. I setup the capture session with the following:

```
//Create session.
AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

//Set preset to low.
if ([session canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetLow]) {
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetLow;
}
else {
    // Handle the failure.
}

//Get camera device.
AVCaptureDevice *device =
[AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

NSError *error = nil;
AVCaptureDeviceInput *input =
[AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
if (!input) {
    //Handle the error appropriately.
}
[session addInput:input];

//Create output.
AVCaptureMovieFileOutput *output = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];
[session addOutput:output];

[session startRunning];
```

I may just be missing something in the developer docs that I'm not seeing, but I haven't seen how to actually get the session to create a file. Any suggestions? Thank you much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keep a reference to the `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`. That will come in handy.

Anyway, there is a method of that class that can be called like so:

```
[[self movieFileOutput] startRecordingToOutputFileURL:url recordingDelegate:self];
```

where `url` is a file URL on the device, such as the documents directory. This allows it to start recording. You also might want to note that you can stop it by calling `[[self movieFileOutput] stopRecording];`. You also need to implement the `AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate` methods to handle callbacks. These methods are called when recording begins and ends, as so:

```
-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput 
               didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)fileURL 
               fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections;

-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput 
               didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL 
               fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error;
```

You must implement these delegate methods to handle what happens when you begin and end recording. In the `didFinishRecording` method, you can then mess around with `AVAssetURL`s, tracks, compositions, and all sorts of things before exporting it as a final movie. Really cool stuff. However it is a decently hard framework and frustrating at times when things seem to be backwards - FYI there are three types of orientations on iOS devices, so the rotation of video will make you want to pull your hair out.

I could literally go on for days about features and frustrations, though, so just be sure to consult Apple's docs whenever possible. This should get you on the right track!

Comment: Very informative. Is the `movieFileOutput` in your code above suppose to be my AVCaptureMovieFileOutput object? Also, I don't suppose you have a link to a descriptive tutorial or some source code of a simple implementation that does this do you?

Comment: Yes it is the AVCaptureMovieFileOutput object. So keeping a reference around is a good idea. I would honestly say the best way to go about all of this is to look at Apple's documentation - there aren't many other resources. Specifically, research `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`, `AVURLAsset`, `AVMutableComposition`, and `AVAssetExportSession`. Most resources deal with `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` which are single frames - ignore those, they are irrelevant here.

Comment: One other question (although perhaps I should add this to a new SO question): How do I get the camera roll URL?

Comment: That might be the topic for another question. I am not sure on that one. If you need to write to the camera roll though, are you sure that you want to be using AVFoundation? Perhaps just using the video function of the UIImagePickerController would work - are you doing video processing, or just simple recording?

Comment: I'm actually looking to do streaming, which looks to be a fairly complicated problem. I'm looking to continuously save small movie files from a capture session and then either serve them or send them to a server. This appears to be the common way video streaming from the iPhone capture has been done else where. If not saving the file to the camera roll where should I probably be saving them?

Comment: I would say the documents directory. Streaming is a complicated problem, but there would be no reason really to store the movie files in the camera roll. It would be unnecessary bloat and, unless there is a reason for the user to access the files outside the app, probably not the best option.

Comment: Got it. And yes, this certainly is a difficult problem for one just starting with iOS, but it's the one I'm working on. Clearly I still have plenty to learn. Thanks again.

Comment: I have use above code for take video but when I save landscape video in Library it's not playing in proper orientation. Any idea ?

Answer (score 7):

Hopefully someone will find this useful, this is a complete example of a swift code recording video into a file:

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

// Video Delegate 
class VideoDelegate : NSObject, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate
{

    func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL outputFileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) {
    println("capture output : finish recording to \(outputFileURL)")
    }

    func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL fileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!) {
        println("capture output: started recording to \(fileURL)")
    }

}
```

After that , calling the startRecordingToOutputFileURL (Assuming session is a AVCaptureSession):

```
let videoDelegate = VideoDelegate()
let fileOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
session.addOutput(fileOutput)
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! NSString
let outputPath = "\(documentsPath)/output.mov"
let outputFileUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: outputPath)
fileOutput.startRecordingToOutputFileURL(outputFileUrl, recordingDelegate: videoDelegate)
```